# Java Full GC - Axis2

Tags: java, garbage-collection, apache-axis

I have a java application connecting to external webservice every 2 mins requesting for data. Once this data is received it is cached locally for business. Web service response is huge (24MB) and I am using axis2 BeanUtil.deserialize to read response before transforming and caching.

I am facing problem where Full GC is kicked in twice in every 2 mins cycle and takes around 2-3 secs.
I am using -Xms512M -Xmx2048M

I have seen application response time slowing down during refresh cycle/ full GC.
I want to know if Full GC is bad for an application and one should tune GC parameters to avoid Full GC?

I have tried various parameters NewRatio, UseConcMarkSweepGC but I can’t see any impact on Full GC & its time duration. Any pointer on this problem will be a great help.

```
 GC trace:
2014-02-05T14:36:32.375+0100: 190.237: [GC 883801K->683780K(1542528K), 0.0884010 secs]
2014-02-05T14:36:36.544+0100: 194.406: [GC 916868K->890923K(1542528K), 0.1139410 secs]
2014-02-05T14:36:38.135+0100: 195.997: [GC 1106423K->1053715K(1542528K), 0.2047740 secs]
2014-02-05T14:36:38.340+0100: 196.202: [Full GC 1053715K->432946K(1589760K), 1.7281700 secs]
2014-02-05T14:36:40.900+0100: 198.762: [GC 666034K->647586K(1589760K), 0.0627390 secs]
2014-02-05T14:36:41.502+0100: 199.364: [GC 1000586K->884464K(1589760K), 0.1304590 secs]
2014-02-05T14:36:42.753+0100: 200.615: [GC 1117552K->1078064K(1589760K), 0.1406750 secs]
2014-02-05T14:36:42.894+0100: 200.756: [Full GC 1078064K->604578K(1864192K), 2.1971060 secs]
2014-02-05T14:36:46.148+0100: 204.010: [GC 837666K->666754K(1864192K), 0.0348680 secs]
2014-02-05T14:36:46.965+0100: 204.828: [GC 899842K->706109K(1864192K), 0.0825090 secs]
```

Regards,
Amber

Comment: `every 2 mins`? Your log shows a separation of four *seconds*.

Comment: You should connect to your app with VisualVM's VisualGC plugin (or the standalone VisualGC tool) and see how the heap generations behave. From the logs it looks like you have a lot of object tenuring going on. Maybe you need to manually increase the Young Generation size. Alternatively -- preferrably, in fact -- rework your application to release the objects more quickly.